# Get name of active slide image and append values to a link in real time

Tags: jquery, dom

I have the following simple slider:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <img src="[the source]/some.jpg" style="display:none" />
    <img src="[the source]/other.jpg" style="display:block" />
</div>
```

What I want is to follow the slideshow changes in real time. If an image has `display:block`, will get the image name, `some` or `other` in this example. If the image name is `some`, will append a button's `href` and `id` attributes with some values, if the image name is `other`, will append a button's (**link**) `href` and `id` attributes with some other values.

Tried the thing below, but that is unuseful. It is not real time. The slides are changing in a 5 seconds interval, this changes interval should be applied also on the link button `href` and `id` values.

```
jQuery(".slideshow img").each(function(i,val){
        if ($('.slideshow img').is(':visible')) {
            var name = $(".slideshow img").attr('src').split('/');
            name = name[name.length-1].split('.')[0];
            if ( name == "oferta" ) {
                $("a.offers").attr("href", "index.php?p=575");
                $("a.offers").attr("id", "of_details");
                console.log(name);
            } else {
                $("a.offers").attr("href", "index.php?p=572");
                $("a.offers").attr("id", "of_valentine ");
            }
        }
    });
```

And unfortunately my slider doesn't applies classes to the active slide image, only is toggling the display attribute.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have used a decent jquery slider plugin, it probably supports running a callback function each time a slide changes.  This provides a good opportunity to do what you're trying to do.  For example, with [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/), your slideshow might be triggered something like this (untested):

```
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
    afterChange: function() {                   
        var images = $('img', '#slider');  // all slideshow images
        var img = images.filter(function() { // find the currently active image
            return ($(this).css('visibility') == 'hidden') ? false : true;
        });
        // Now determine img name and manipulate accordingly
    }
});
```

Comment: it's a jQuery slideshow plugin and this is how he generates the slideshow :)